# How to redeclare already created object values in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have an assignment to create a small game

Build a Text Adventure Game which takes user input and performs certain actions.

// At the start of the game the user is given the choice to choose a type of player (1, 2, 3)
// Each type of player starts with below attributes -

// Player 1 - max health = 50, damage = 10, heal = 20

// Player 2 - max health = 75, damage = 25, heal = 10

// Player 3 - max health = 100, damage = 75, heal = 20

problem is when I try to redeclare the object it doesnt change

```
Player player(0,0,0);
int player_no;
bool gameover=false;

 std::cout<<"choose your player !!!";
 std::cin>>player_no;
 if(player_no==1){
   Player player1(50,20,10); //value is not reflected inside while
   std::cout<<player.heal;  //50
   std::cout<<player.health; //20
   goto start;
 }else if(player_no==2){
   Player player(75,10,25);  //value is not reflcted inside while
   goto start;
 }


 char command;
  start:
 while(!gameover){
   std::cout<<"what do you want ??? ";
   std::cin>>command;
   if(command=='D'){
     std::cout<<player.health<<"\n";  //uses the default value 0
      std::cout<<player.damage<<"\n";  //uses the default value 0
     player.TakeDamage(player.damage);  //0 is passed
   }else if(command=='H') {
       player.Heal(player.heal);         // 0 is passed
   }
```

How to pass the changed value inside the while ???

Comment: I am new to C++

Comment: What's `Player`? What's `TakeDamage`, what's `Heal`? Where's your `main` function?

Comment: Any players that you create inside the body of an if-statement will be deleted from memory when the if-statement exits. Actually, because it has a `goto`, I'm not sure what happens... This will be a good learning experience for me

Comment: I don't think you gave enough context. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: ***Player player(75,10,25);  //value is not reflcted inside while*** Creates a new `player` variable which has no connection to the `player` variable in the outer scope. This variable exists only for the block it is inside.

Comment: How to solve the issue then ?? if user selects player 1 I want only his data to be used for the game

Comment: You will need to change the values in the existing `player` object

Comment: what about `player = Player(50,20,10);` instead of `Player player1(50,20,10);`

Comment: without using conditionals how to change the value of existing object respecting scope ???

Comment: ***without using conditionals how to change the value of existing object respecting scope*** That depends on how you defined your `Player` class. `player = Player(50,20,10);` may work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiny example to illustrate your problem:

```
    int a = 2;
    if (a == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
        int a = 3;
        std::cout << "a set to " << a << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
```

This prints:

```
a is 2
a set to 3
a is 2
```

Why is `a` not 3 in the second line? That is because the braces `{ ... }` declare a new scope and the line `int a = 3` declares a new `a` variable that is local to that scope only. The second we leave the if-scope the second `a` variable dies, and we are left with only the original which still is set to 2.

If we change it to:

```
    int a = 2;
    if (a == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
        a = 3;
        std::cout << "a set to " << a << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
```

Then no new `a` is declared, and the assignment refers to the variable in the outer scope. Now the output is:

```
a is 2
a set to 3
a is 3
```

The fix to your code is to do something like this:

```
Player player(0, 0, 0);
...
if (player_no == 1) {
    player = Player(50, 20, 10);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problem :
1) The name of the variable : 
You call player on 1st line and player1 after if (player_no==1){...

2) The scope is not respected : 
when you created anew Player player(75,10,25); it doesnt replace the first created Player.

I will prefer use pointer like that (there are infinite way to do it !) :

```
Player* pPlayer = NULL;
...
if(player_no==1){
pPlayer = new Player(50, 20, 10);
...
if(player_no==2){
pPlayer = new Player(75, 10, 25);
...
if (pPlayer != NULL) {
   while(!gameover) {
       if (command == 'D') {
           pPlayer->Damage();
       }
   }
delete pPlayer;
}
```

Hope it helps you !